# Method that executes a continuation of a Task in the main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have to create a method, that similar to `ContinueWith()`, but will execute continuation in main thread, after main Task.

How can I do that?
I could endlessly checking the state of `Task` in my method, and when it finishes start continuation, but I think it couldn`t work in such way:

```
Task<DayOfWeek> taskA = new Task<DayOfWeek>(() => DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);

Task<string> continuation = taskA.OurMethod((antecedent) =>
{
    return String.Format("Today is {0}.", antecedent.Result);
});
// Because we endlessly checking state of main Task
// Code below will never execute

taskA.Start();
```

So what I could do here?

Comment: Define "main thread". Why can't you just write a regular `async` method? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to understand what kind of a code example is actually a good one.

Comment: Thread A should create an AutoResetEvent, and pass a reference to it to thread B when it creates thread B, and then wait on the AutoResetEvent. Thread B, when it is finished doing its work, should "set" the AutoResetEvent that thread A is waiting on.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: the more appropriate question is, what version of .NET are you running? Async/await is 4.5 syntax.

Comment: @RenniePet hmm,very interesting way! I`ll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing around the "main" thread's `Dispatcher`. Example:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
{
    // blah
}
.ContinueWith(task=>
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>
    {
        // yay, on the UI thread...
    }
}
```

Assuming that the "main" thread is UI thread. If it's not, then grab that thread's dispatcher after you make it. Use *that* dispatcher instead of `Application.Current`'s (i.e. `CurrentDispatcher`).

Comment: The "continuations should take care of that for you" line appears incorrect.

Comment: By default continuations are executed on `TaskScheduler.Current`, which, unless you're scheduling your continuation from within the body of another task, is `TaskScheduler.Default`. This means that in *most* cases the continuation will execute on the thread pool regardless of which thread started the task, and which thread the original `ContinueWith` call was made on. If you wish the continuation to be posted back to the appropriate `SynchronizationContext`, you will invariably need to use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I missed that subtlety. According to msdn: `A continuation is itself a Task and does not block the thread on which it is started. Use the Wait method to block until the continuation task finishes.`

Comment: Thank you! I`m new in C#, so i don`t know about that great possibility!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `ExtensionMethod` for a process like this. Here is an example implementation

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Task ContinueOnUI(this Task task, Action continuation)
    {
        return task.ContinueWith((arg) =>
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(continuation);
        });
    }
}
```

Consume it like this.

```
Task run = new Task(() =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Testing");
});
run.ContinueOnUI(() =>
{
    Notify += "\nExecuted On UI"; // Notify is bound on a UI control
});
run.Start();
```

Comment: Looks like almost what i need,but if i understand my task right,i can`t use ContinueWith,it have to be my own method...(

Comment: @progerz that's where you pass your Action delegate